# Is there any PNG-fix for IE 6 and without modifying current HTML, CSS and image name?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, png, internet-explorer-6

Is there any PNG-fix for IE 6 and without modifying current HTML, CSS and image name?

any javascript way.

I can add any thing in `<head>........</head>` but can't modify anythings inside `<body>.....</body>`.

in one shot i want to make transparent all png transparent.

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question many times before?

Comment: Yes, it's called uninstallation.

Comment: Why negative marking? strange.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - No . I haven't asked same question before.

Answer (score 2):

As I just learned, [this script](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) will make IE behave like a standards compliant browser, including PNG fixes.

Comment: i need without modifying current css and HTML

Comment: ok i got your point . I can do via this method for all PNG `var IE7_PNG_SUFFIX = ".png";`

Answer (score 2):

OK here's a question: if you can't modify the HTML, CSS or image at all, what the heck *can* you modify? The raw network stream coming from the server?

Comment: i can add anything inside `<head>` but not inside `<body>`

Comment: In that case, Kyle's solution will work, just put the javascript in the head of the document.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred PNGFix is [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/). It is easy to use, example from the page:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script src="DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>
<script>
  /* EXAMPLE */
  DD_belatedPNG.fix('.png_bg');

  /* string argument can be any CSS selector */
  /* .png_bg example is unnecessary */
  /* change it to what suits you! */
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can set that `.png_bg` selector to whatever you see fit. Perhaps you want to replace all of the headings on a page: `DD_belatedPNG.fix('h1,h2,h3');`

Answer (score 0):

This can be fix in 2 way

1. There is a fix file called png-fix.js, just get from net and include it before your `</body>` tag.
2. Better you can change you png file format into png-8 format via the photo-shop tool.

Comment: #2 is not a solution: the fix is also needed in case of 8-bit PNG with alpha transparency. http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/09/18/png8-the-clear-winner/