# How to make inline png <img> transparent using css?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6, png-24

How to make inline png transparent inside div? using css

```
<div id="report'>
<p> some text </p>

<img src=transparent.png" />

</p>

</div>
```

this is image for example . Other than ball i want to make transparent other white area. Which is looking grey in IE6

[image]

I want to do in css like this `div#report img {.....}` is it possible?

Edit:

I don't want to make whole image transparent

**Update:**

Here i added example http://jsbin.com/ubabo3

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE6 PNG transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any PNG-fix for IE 6 and without modifying current HTML, CSS and image name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817849/is-there-any-png-fix-for-ie-6-and-without-modifying-current-html-css-and-image-n)

Comment: It's a duplicate of at least 2 questions 'metal-gear-solid' has asked before...

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - What you found duplicate? just read the title of both question once again

Answer (score 2):

IE 6 does not support transparent png files per default. You need to use a small hack to achieve transparent png files.

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B294714&x=12&y=11

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div#report img{
    background-color/**/: #000000;
    background-image/**/: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) property applies to all elements (in supporting browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but you can make an image completely transparent (i.e. invisible):

```
div#report img { visibility: hidden } // Still takes up space
div#report img { display: none } // Hidden entirely -
```

it is not possible, however, to apply this only to png images, at least not in CSS 2.1. It's surely possible using some additional jQuery magic by using a selector that checks for `.png` in the `src` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add support for PNG translucency to IE6 using CSS. There are hacks (some of which involve, IIRC, calling ActiveX stuff into a stylesheet) and [Google will find lots for you](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ie%206%20png%20fix).

(These days, however, I'd note that IE6 is just a few weeks away from End of Life, has a small marketshare among my target audience, and refuse to do extra work to persuade it to look nice)

Comment: I'm asking for inline image? I tried a lot on google but haven't found any good solution. i want to do like this `div#report img {.....}`

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with IE6 PNG problems before and this worked ..

what you do is add a "behavior" attribute to your

```
div#report img { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc) }
```

and you can download the file - iepngfix.htc [here](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) and check the [online demonstration](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/) .. it explains everything step by step